# Is it wrong to store all shared data in the parent component?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture, components

I am working with AngularJS 1.6.

I am working in a system in which the shared data is stored in a top level component. The child components access the parent through:

```
require: {
  'parentView': '?^'
}
```

and access the data with `{{thisView.parentView.variable}}` and `this.parentView.changeVar(var);`

This seems like an *anti-pattern*. It seems that the "right" solution would be to use a service to store and change the data.

What is actually the issue with the `parentView` approach?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I see is that child components are hardly reusable in such scenario since they are tightly coupled with parent component.
So that's why injecting service with data is more preferable and easier to test with unit tests. And unit tests prevent your code to become legacy.

Comment: So if a component's logical place in the application is definitely under the particular parent, then do you see any differences in the two approaches?

Comment: Sorry, just noticed it is angular 1. I mean child components may be used later with some other parent component, and all it needs is input data without knowing where this data is located in parent scope. Do in case of reuse you should ajust parent to store data in specefic variable.

Answer (score 0):

Services and parent controllers aren't to be compared. Services are great, but the data will eventually have to be used in the scope. If that scope happens to be a parent controller, child controllers should be able to access it as well, instead of creating another scope of its own.

Comment: The comparison is that conceptually they are both serving as a singleton to store the data. Every component creates its own scope AFAIK and the data can be passed in to the child and the child can call the parent callbacks that were passed to it. The above, as well as services, are recommended approaches. The approach in the application I am working with is to access the data directly by accessing the parent scope. This seems 'wrong' though I am trying to figure out if it warrants a refactor.

Comment: Yes, they both can store data. Personally, I store all data in services, but would only attach those data in the scope as minimally as needed. services are mainly useful in communicating between directives and controllers that arent parent/child. So if its a parent/child, its best to keep the usage of the parent scope, instead of creating another object in the child's scope.